# How to implement an OWIN Authentication server with a MVC Web Api content server and an Android end-user apk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to implement:

1. An MVC Web API server to return content on-demand (REST Server)
2. A Central authentication OAuth 2.0 server (for example OWIN)
3. An Android end-user side Application

The Scenario is like this: Android application requests content on REST Server, if its token is expired, REST server makes a request on authentication server to identify the client. The REST server should be registered using its own **[id,secret]** on authentication server and then Android application should be informed to identify on central authentication server using end-user **[username,password]** and Android application **[id,secret]**.

So REST server must be registered on authentication server using fixed **[id,secret]**.
Android application must be registered on authentication server using fixed **[id,secret]** and end-user **[username,password]**.

So the problem is most samples on the web use cookie based sessions that cannot be used via a REST server and a non-browser end user (at least it is not recommended). I did not find a clear example to explain the implementation of this scenario or even some part of this, all that I found were some beginner code snippets.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you posts on [Token Based Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and [Enable OAuth Refresh Tokens](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) from Taiseer Joudeh, wich teaches you step by step in the process to create a token based Authentication (mobile friendly, without cookies storage) and refreshtoken for managing token expiration.

Note: Don't be afraid if the post title talks about "AngularJS". You can skip this part.

Comment: Thank you @Freerider for your quick help!
I read your link and it helped me to find out how to implement my own custom OAuth-OWIN project, but still a question remains: Does using OAuth without SSL guarantee the security? (I think this is just another authentication mechanism and does not do anything about encryption)
And if you are familiar with Java.Spring.Greenhouse project is it also true about it?

Comment: @HosseinBakhtiari You're welcome. SSL for OAuth2 is mandatory because username and password are sent in the first request for token, so you must use it to encrypt username and password in your communications. SSL is just an asymmetric and symmetric encryption algorithm where both parts (browser and webserver) trust on a third party and relies on it data encryption and decryption. So SSL is totally related to encryption. One of the critiscims on OAuth2 that at the end the security relies on SSL and not in own OAuth2 protocol. I'm sorry, but I'm not aware of the Java.Spring.Greenhouse project.